# Error reading entity from input stream on null list

Tags: jackson, jax-rs

I'm attempting to call a REST endpoint that returns JSON for a validated civic address.  On a successful call, I get back something like this:

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "civicnumberid":123456,
         "civic_address_as_string":"123 Main Street, My City, My Municipality, My County",
         "esri_point":{  
            "x":12345.678,
            "y":54321.012
         }
      }
   ],
   "error":null
}
```

However if I send a request in a format that the service can't handle, I back back something like this:

```
{  
   "success":false,
   "results":null,
   "error":{  
      "code":123,
      "message":"Invalid Civic Address. Valid Example: 123 Main St, My City...",
      "details":[  
         "The civic address submitted to the service contained an alphabetic character where a number was expected."
      ]
   }
}
```

Note the ***"results": null***.  While attempting to convert the response using JAX-RS 2.0 and Jackson 2.5.1:

```
ResponseObject response = client.target(url)
    .path(REST_REQUEST_CONTEXT)
    .queryParam("search_str", searchAddress)
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .get(ResponseObject.class);
```

... it fails with "Error reading entity from input stream."  Here's my current ObjectMapper setup:

```
    defaultObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
   .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
   .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS, true)
   .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
   .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
   .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
```

My ResponseObject is a JAXB object:

```
public class ResponseObject
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Boolean success;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<Result> results;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected Error error;
```

Can ***"results": null*** be handled gracefully or should I work with the service provider to return an empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong in assuming that the null results was the issue.  The Error jaxb type was defined using the following schema type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Error">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="details" nillable="true"
            type="q1:ArrayOfstring" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

... which resulted in the following JAXB type:

```
public class Error {

     protected Integer code;
     @XmlElement(nillable = true)
     protected String message;
     @XmlElement(nillable = true)
     protected ArrayOfstring details;
```

But when I changed the schema to this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Error">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <!-- 
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="details" nillable="true"
            type="q1:ArrayOfstring" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
             -->
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="details" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

... The following JAXB type works:

```
public class Error {

     private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     protected Integer code;
     @XmlElement(nillable = true)
     protected String message;
     @XmlElement(nillable = true)
     protected List<String> details;
```